# probability question show that $P(A)>P(B)$

Tags: probability-theory

This question comes up several times in past exam papers so i would really like to work it out! Here is it:

Assume that $$0<P(C)<1.$$

How would I show that if 
 $P(A|C)> P(B|C)$ and $P(A|C^c)> P(B|C^c) $

Then $P(A)>P(B)$

My solution:

I have so far that the conditional probability of an event A given event B, denoted by 
 $P(A|B),$ is defined as

$$P(A|B) = P(A\cap B)/P(B)$$and similarly  $$P(B|A) = P(A\cap B)/P(A)$$ with $$P(A)>0, P(B)>0$$

I know that i must need to use these but i dont really know how, i can see that if  $P(A|C)> P(B|C)$ and $P(A|C^c)> P(B|C^c) $

Then $P(A)>P(B)$

but i dont know how to show this...

Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: Hint: $P(A) = P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap C^c)$

Comment: thank you but how can this lead to $P(A)>P(B)$?

Comment: I'll write an answer but I really think you should look a little closer with my hint before you check :)

Comment: I answered this quite recently--Oh well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(A|C) > P(B|C) \implies P(A\cap C) = P(A|C)P(C) > P(B|C)P(C) = P(B\cap C)$.

$P(A|C^c) > P(B|C^c)\implies P(A\cap C^c)= P(A|C^c)P(C^c) > P(B|C^c)P(C^c) = P(B\cap C^c)$

So,

$P(A \cap C) > P(B \cap C)$ and $P(A \cap C^c) > P(B \cap C^c)$
$ \implies
P(A) = P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap C^c)>P(B \cap C) + P(B \cap C^c) = P(B)$

Comment: Thank you so much thats amazing! completely makes sense. Thanks :)